# How can i fix Delete in cart

Tags: php, web

**When i delete my items from my cart this error shows;**

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\FinalsActivity1\delete.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\FinalsActivity1\delete.php on line 5
```

**CODES

```
 <?php
    require("config.php");
    require('header.php');
   ***LINE 5*** $itemsql = "SELECT * FROM orderitems WHERE id = ". $_GET['id'] . ";";
    $itemres = mysqli_query($dbdatabase, $itemsql) or die(mysqli_error($itemsql));
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($itemres);
    if($numrows == 0) {
    header("Location: showcart.php");
    }
 .
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround your variables in quotes. In your example, it would be:

```
$itemsql = "SELECT * FROM orderitems WHERE id = '". $_GET['id'] . "';";
```

And

```
$prodsql = "SELECT price FROM products WHERE id = '" . $itemrow['product_id'] . "';";
```

This is because, assuming, your ID's are actually `int`s therefore when you're placing them in the query without quotes it's handling them as an `int`. By surrounding them in quotes it forces the query to interpret it as a string.